# How can I include a template inside another template?

Tags: django, templates, include

Im new to programming and I looking if there is there a way that I can include a template inside other template. Im working on a project that I want to display on the same page a content of a certain topic and flashcards to test my knowledge of this topic, and Im stuck when trying to display my cards on the same page (I could only make it work using another url). Here is what I have so far:

models.py:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="topic", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('topic:topic-detail', kwargs={
                       "topic_slug": self.slug,})

class Deck(models.Model):
    deckTopic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=510, null=False, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def get_number_of_cards(self):
        '''
        Returns the number of cards in the decks related card_set
        '''
        return self.card_set.count()
    get_number_of_cards.short_description = 'Card Count'


class Card(models.Model):
    parentDeck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    front = models.TextField()
    back = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.front

    def has_prev_card(self):
        '''
        Returns true if card is not thee first card in the deck.
        '''
        first_card_in_deck = self.parentDeck.card_set.first()
        if self == first_card_in_deck:
            return False
        return True

    def get_prev_card(self):
        '''
        Return previous card in deck
        '''
        return self.parentDeck.card_set.filter(id__lt=self.id).last()

    def has_next_card(self):
        '''
        Returns true if card is not the last card in the deck.
        '''
        last_card_in_deck = self.parentDeck.card_set.last()
        if self == last_card_in_deck:
            return False
        return True

    def get_next_card(self):
        '''
        Return next card in deck
        '''
        return self.parentDeck.card_set.filter(id__gt=self.id).first()
```

views.py:

```
class TopicDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Topic

def viewDeck(request, deck_id):
    '''
    Gets the deck from the database.
    Return first card in deck unless card_id is specified in url.
    '''

    deck_obj = get_object_or_404(Deck, id=deck_id)
    card_list = deck_obj.card_set.all()
    card_obj = card_list.first()
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'card' in request.GET:
        card_obj = get_object_or_404(Card, id=request.GET['card'])

    context = {
        'deck_obj': deck_obj,
        'card_obj': card_obj,
    }
    return render(request, 'topic/viewDeck.html', context)
```

topic_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="topic-title">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
        {{object.title}}
        </h5>
</div>

<div class="topic-body">
        <p class="mb-0">
        {{object.body}}
        </p>
</div>

<!--Here is where I want to include the flashcard--!>
 <div class="topic-deck">                    
       {% for deck in object.deck_set.all %}
       {{deck.description}}
       <a href="{% url 'topic:viewDeck' deck.id %}">Flashcard</a>
       {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

viewDeck.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="deck-container">
    <div class="deck-header">
        <div class="deck-header-title">
            <h1>{{deck_obj}}</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="deck-header-actions">
            <p>Return to Topic</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    {% if card_obj %}
    <div class="notecard">
        <div class="notecard-nav text-center">
            {% if card_obj.has_prev_card %}
            <a href="{% url 'topic:viewDeck' deck_obj.id %}?card= 
            {{card_obj.get_prev_card.id}}">Prev</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if card_obj.has_next_card %}
            <a href="{% url 'topic:viewDeck' deck_obj.id %}?card= 
            {{card_obj.get_next_card.id}}">Next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="notecard-front">
            <p class="text-center">Front</p>
            <p>{{card_obj.front}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="notecard-back">
            <p class="text-center">Back</p>
            <p>{{card_obj.back}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% else %}

    <p>No card found.</p>

    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a way to see deckView inside topic_detail.html? Sorry if I didn't made myself clear.

Update:
I tried inserting {% include 'viewDeck.html' %} as passing the context deck_obj, card_list and card_obj to topic_detail.html, but it gives me this error: NameError: name 'deck_id' is not defined. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build the url correctly ?
To be able to pass the deck_id like you did in your view, you have to tell your url that you want to pass some data in, by writing something like this in your urls.py :

```
from name_of_your_app import views

url(r'deck/(?P<deck_id>\d+)/$', views.viewDeck , name='name_of_you_url'),
```

(?P<deck_id>\d+) is the important part, as it indicates that you will receive a numerical data which can be called with the name "deck_id".

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks for the tip!!